# Meaning of 蟗
(qiū)

Tags: word-requests

My dictionary has an entry for 蟗 (qiū), but no explanation is given. Here is the entry from the Pleco Android app.

[image: Pleco entry I]

[image: Pleco entry II]

What does this mean, and why is the dictionary entry missing?

Thanks.

Comment: bkrs：蟗 亦作“蝵”。即蜘蛛

Comment: @JackMaddington be nice to yourself and buy a copy of 汉语大词典 in pleco - you'll find it has an explanation for this character.

Comment: Thank you for your addition. I would love to purchase it, such a useful dictionary, might do so.

Answer (score 2):

次蟗 means spider and it is not commonly (very very rarely) used in modern Chinese.

Source:

[http://hanyu.baidu.com/zici/s?wd=蟗&tupu=01](http://hanyu.baidu.com/zici/s?wd=%E8%9F%97&tupu=01)

http://zidian.eduu.com/detail/14985.html

http://www.zdic.net/z/23/kx/87d7.htm